# Make nginx and node.js have a common root folder

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I have set up an Ubuntu server (16.04), installed nodejs and nginx, and made them work fine one by one. nodejs on port 3000, and nginx on port 80.

The only problem for me now is the ftp. I would like to have the js-files for nodejs reside in a sub-folder of nginx www folder, or vice versa. So I can upload all files at once.

I have tried to make a symbolic link in nginx /var/www/html/my_web_project, leading to a folder in nodejs, /home/admin/www/my_web_project.
..But I run into endless problem with access denied.

Admins home-folder are encrypted, maybe could lead to problems?

Anyway, I would not mind having a folder somewhere, where both nginx and nodejs expected to find their files in their respective sub-folder.

Is that a good way to go, and can someone give me some advice on how to do it?

Comment: Use `/usr/share/nginx/html` which is usually the default Nginx location. Make sure the user that runs Node has read access to those files (read up on Linux file permissions in relation to users & groups). **Never run Nginx nor Node as root user!** I also suggest reading up on Linux [directory structure](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html) to understand what all these locations means.

Comment: In my installation, nginx reside in /var/www/html, I assume it is the same. You mean I put the node-files (a single javascript file in my case) there, and I would be done. I will test this tomorrow and come back, dead tired. :)Thank's a lot.

Comment: It seems to vary, on my installation nginx points to `/usr/share/nginx/html`, but `/var/www/html` is well. However if it is a Node script (that you're not supposed to send to browsers) you should put it in a place that Nginx doesn't have access to, e.g `/usr/local/myapp` or similar.

Comment: @Svenskunganka, I have tried to install and uninstall nginx like, a hundred times now. It refuses to install unless I write "sudo" before the "apt-get" command. After installation, it has created a folder "/var/www/html" folder. I want to create a sub-folder in there, which I also has to create with "sudo", otherwise it is created as another user. I have a index.html file created by myself (not root) which I want to copy into this folder. Sure, but then nginx cannot read the file because it is created by another user.... OMG! HOW DO I DO THIS?! Is there a certain way to make this workable?

Comment: `chown` it to the user (which is usually `www-data`). Note that you can also run commands as another user with `sudo -u www-data mkdir somedir`. *Installing* software always requires root access (e.g `sudo`), but you should *run* nginx as `www-data` user (which is the default) and not under `root`, same with your node script (possibly as `www-data` but any user without `sudo` access will do)

Comment: Thank you for all your tips. After lots of reading, I think I got the main idea with Linux security thinking and solved it! I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux has a steep learning curve, but it is actually worth the trouble because I got a working solution at last.

Start with installing nginx. Even if you are going to do most development in nodejs, you will need a working web server, which is nginx.

I skimmed these guides:

https://serverfault.com/questions/433265/how-do-i-change-the-nginx-user

https://nevyan.blogspot.se/2016/01/install-setup-nginx-php-mysql-and-ftp.html

The guides boils down to these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf    
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Edit nginx.conf, instruct nginx to run with user 'my_user':

```
user my_user;
```

Edit default config, the crucial line here:

```
root /home/my_user/ftp/files;
```

Then restart your nginx server.

What should be the result? Simple; I can upload files via ftp to my web server.

1. I connect with 'my_user' via ftp or sftp, and since it is my users home-folder, I can overwrite the files. Avoids most difficulties with linux file security. (I have a hard time grasping all of it.)
2. Since nginx are running with user 'my_user', it also can access the /home/my_user/ftp/files folder! (I almost gone insane getting this step working)
3. The root-folder for nginx are set to be /home/my_user/ftp/files, so when I upload a new version of index.html to that folder, nginx immediately use it.

Works. :)

nodejs was easy peasy to install, it seem to "just work out of the box". I basically followed this guide: https://kyup.com/tutorials/install-run-node-js-application/

I wanted websocket too, which was the easiest part:

```
sudo npm install websocket
```

Hope it helps someone, I had fun making this work. :)